# How can i extract the event subscription in an own method without reducing performance

Tags: c#, events, iteration, ienumerable

I have a WPF Application where I regularly have to convert `DataTables` from a `SQLClient` into `ObservableCollections` of models. In order to reduce code I have created an extension Method called `ToObservableCollection()` to do this conversion for me, which I designed to be as dynamic as possible.

There are quite a few times where I need to subscribe to the `OnPropertyChanged` event for every model in a list. I didn't want to basically do the same iteration twice (once when creating the Models, and once when subscribing to their `OnPropertyChanged` event), so I tried to subscribe when creating the model during conversion like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this DataTable source, IEnumerable<PropertyChangedEventHandler> subscriptions = null) where T : ModelBase
    {
        ObservableCollection<T> collection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        foreach (DataRow row in source.Rows)
        {
            var obj = Convert<T>(row); //not important for this example
            Subscribe(obj, subscriptions);
            collection.Add(obj);
        }
        return collection;
    }
```

while the subscription is done like this:

```
    private static void Subscribe<T>(T obj, IEnumerable<PropertyChangedEventHandler> subscriptions) where T: ModelBase 
    {
       if(subscripitons != null)
         foreach(PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged in subscriptions)
         {
            obj.PropertyChanged += propertyChanged;
         }
    }
```

This approach works, however my real `ToObservableCollection` has more parameters and is a lot more convoluted than my example here. In an effort to make this method less messy, I want to clean up parameters a little and the subscriptions are probably the least used.

But since I am working with collection that regularly contain a few thousand items, I also feel like adding the subscriptions here is important for performance. The alternative would be:

```
     var list = dt.ToObservableCollection<SomeModel>();
     foreach(var item in list) 
     {   
         //I am aware for-loops and Spans would be better if performance is of an issue
         //this is just an example
         obj.PropertyChanged += SomeViewModel_ModelPropertyChanged;
         obj.PropertyChanged += OtherViewModel_ModelPropertyChanged;
     }
```

**Is there a way to split the event subscriptions from my `ToObeservableCollection` method without having to iterate a second time?**

Comment: "...however my real ToObservableCollection has more parameters and is a lot more convoluted than my example here..."
Please share your real method :)

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant here. My Convert<T>() method turns a DataRow into a model. It's pretty long because it needs to handle some annoying edge-cases, but that is hardly relevant, as it only uses an Activator to create a new model of type T and then fills it with data taken from the DataRow. It is hardly relevant how the model is filled though, as I want to split off the Subscirbe() method, which is shown completely.

Comment: When you are dealing with performance issues, you need to be aware of new object instances. It is not only related to your subscriptions and loops, it is mostly related to new instances of managed objects.

Comment: @PedroPaulo I don't disagree and I certainly can optimize some areas with greater gains, but that's not my question. I want to know if there is a way to split off the Subscribe() method without redundantly iterating through the same set of data twice in short succession, since i feel that the current method strayed too far from any clean code principles.